# How do I go about getting fonts to render the right way via Interface Builder

Tags: interface, interface-builder

I always run into problems with Interface Builder and selecting fonts. My computer never seems to get fonts right. How to you render font in the iPad?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this same annoyance. The Font window can get sort of disconnected from the particular View that has focus. In general, if you close the Font window, select the view that you want to adjust and then reopen the Font window (shortcut is cmd-t) then the fonts should update appropriately.

Comment: It is very buggy, some fonts just don't show up no matter what I do. E.g.: TRAJAN PRO